# Why ExpenseLineRetList return null

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I saw [this link](https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/689989-help-me-i-try-get-data-expenses-error) and I notice we have the same problem, and his question still didn't answer yet.

Here is the question.

```
public class ServiceSel
    {
        public void GetCheqe()
        {
            bool sessionBegun = false;
            bool connectionOpen = false;
            QBSessionManager rp = null;

        try
        {
            rp = new QBSessionManager();
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = rp.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;
            rp.OpenConnection("Database Path File QuickBooks", "QuickBooks Integration Demo");
            connectionOpen = true;
            rp.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
            sessionBegun = true;

            ICheckQuery checkQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendCheckQueryRq();
            IMsgSetResponse msgSetRs = rp.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
            IResponse response = msgSetRs.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
            ICheckRetList checkRetList = (ICheckRetList)response.Detail;

            if (checkRetList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkRetList.Count; i++)
                {
                        ICheckRet checkRet = checkRetList.GetAt(i);
                        //Bank Account On top 
                        string TxnID = checkRet.TxnID.GetValue().ToString();       //Data correct
                        string TxnNumber = checkRet.TxnNumber.GetValue().ToString();   //Data correct
                        string Account = checkRet.AccountRef.FullName.GetValue();   //Data correct
                        string Amount = checkRet.Amount.GetValue().ToString();   //Data correct

                         if (checkRet.ExpenseLineRetList != null)
                         {
                                 Error checkRet.Expense Show null Data But in quickbooks have many data expense in calendar 

                         }      
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sessionBegun)
            {
                rp.EndSession();
            }
            if (connectionOpen)
            {
                rp.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

    }
```

Why ExpenseLineRetList is null?

Comment: Please follow [these guideslines](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to see how to help yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check request will not include the detail lines of the check unless you include it in your query. By adding the `IncludeLineItems` setting, you'll get access to the Expense or Item lists of the check (a check could have Expense lines, Item lines, or both). You'll want to change to include the following:

```
ICheckQuery checkQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendCheckQueryRq();
checkQuery.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);
IMsgSetResponse msgSetRs = rp.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
```

I would also suggest that you check the response code before trying to get the response detail so you can better handle errors:

```
IResponse response = msgSetRs.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
if(response.StatusCode != 0)
{
    // There was an error. response.StatusCode has the error number
    // response.StatusMessage has the error description.
}
else
{        
    ICheckRetList checkRetList = (ICheckRetList)response.Detail;
    .
    .
    .
}
```