# Cannot get the value of ExpenseLineRetList in QuickBooks C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

Hello I'm Having problem getting the ExpensesList in Cheque in Quickbooks
Here is my code:

```
bool sessionBegun = false;
            bool connectionOpen = false;
            QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;
            try
            {
                //Create the session Manager object
                sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

                //Create the message set request object to hold our request
                IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
                requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

                //Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
                sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "Sample Code from OSR");
                connectionOpen = true;
                sessionManager.BeginSession(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\EsdeSolosyon.QBW", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
                sessionBegun = true;

                ICheckQuery checkQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCheckQueryRq();

                //Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
                IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
                IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
                ICheckRetList checkRetList = (ICheckRetList)response.Detail;

                if (checkRetList != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkRetList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ICheckRet checkRet = checkRetList.GetAt(i);
                        IExpenseLineRetList expenseList = checkRetList.GetAt(i).ExpenseLineRetList;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
```

In my picture the expenseslist returns null and in my Quickbooks program
[image]

But in my QuickBooks every cheque has expenses
[image]

BTW in quickbooks you cannot add Cheque if you don't have any ExpensesList

Comment: I can't retrieve or query the expenseslist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same issue as here: [Why ExpenseLineRetList return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754202/why-expenselineretlist-return-null)

A check request will not include the detail lines of the check unless you include it in your query. By adding the `IncludeLineItems` setting, you'll get access to the Expense or Item lists of the check (a check could have Expense lines, Item lines, or both). You'll want to change to include the following:

```
ICheckQuery checkQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCheckQueryRq();

// Include the line details with the request
checkQueryRq.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);

//Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
```